# How do we get veterinarians to participate on our site?

Tags: discussion

Although many questions can be answered by owners of the specified pet, some will definitely need the expertise of a vet. How do we introduce veterinarians to the site? Should we tell users to tell their vet about it next time they visit?

Comment: I don't have good answer here. Its been suggested previously that there may be restrictions placed on the vet by their accreditation board in some countries that might prevent them from answering questions.

Comment: @psubsee2003 great point about the accreditation board thing.

Comment: addressed in part here http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/37/do-we-have-experts-here/44#44

Answer (score 5):

We are still in private beta probably until early next week.  But as the cliche goes "Build it and they will come".  If we ask high quality questions and do not reward low quality answers we will draw in experts including Vets.